# Sort managed data sources in Looker Studio by name

Tags: looker-studio

When viewing a report, I can click on the "Resource" tab and select the "Manage added data sources" option

[image: data sources option]

It opens a view where all my data sources are listed. However, they are not sorted and seem to be random. How can I sort them by name?

[image: sort not present]